# JavaScript remove keys of object and keep same order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object or array (i am not sure) that looks like this:

```
0:{62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"}
1:{61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"}
2:{55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}
...
```

My goal is to make it look like this:

```
62:"01:30:00 - 01:45:00"
61:"01:30:00 - 01:45:00"
...
```

I need to keep the same order as in the first object this is very important.
I've tried this but the result is the exact same.

```
finalOptions = [];
for (var newKey in newOptions) {
    finalOptions.push(newOptions[newKey]);
}

console.log(finalOptions);
```

Comment: If your desire is to have an object with properties named `62`, `61`, `55` *in that order*, then this is a MUST read: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/1220550)

Comment: @MichaelMontero I don't know, how can I know this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var myObject = {
  0:{62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  1:{61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  2:{55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}
};

var newObject = {};
for (s in myObject) {
  for (ss in myObject[s])
    newObject[ss] = myObject[s][ss];
}

console.log(newObject);
```

This if you want to keep the orignal order

```js
var myObject = {
  0:{62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  1:{61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  2:{55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}
};

var newObject = [];
for (s in myObject) {
  for (ss in myObject[s])
    newObject.push(myObject[s][ss]);
}

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for down voting

Comment: I get a very weird result in my console "createCallback createDelegate etc." nothing at all that looks like the snippet

Comment: Which browser are you using? If you click on the "Run code snippet", result will appear just below the snippet, not in the browser console

Comment: I am using chrome my starting data is an Array and I want and Object as result, basically I need to remove the array positions and make an object of the results

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Array of object you can try:

```js
var ar = [{0: {62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"}, 1: {61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},2: { 55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00" }}]
 
var result;
for (el of ar) {
  for (obj in el) {
    for (text in el[obj]) {
      result = el[obj][text];result 
      console.log(result)
    }
  }
}
```

But if you have An object, you can try this:

```js
var obj = {
              0: { 62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00" },
              1: { 61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00" },
              2: { 55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00" }
          };
var result;
for (key in obj) {
  for (el in obj[key]) {
    result = obj[key][el];
    console.log(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you do a console.log? I need an abject of all the items as result

Comment: I just print what you call `result`. You can do whatever you want with that. I've updated my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

what you have is an array of objects. What you are trying to do is read objects from array1 (newOptions) and assign to array2 (finalOptions). Results will definitely be same.

[image]

This is the way Chrome Developer Console will show arrays to understand array index and corresponding values

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with an array of objects, you can use `.reduce()` method:

```js
let data = [
  {62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  {61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
  {55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}
];

let result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  let [[k, v]] = Object.entries(c);
  a[k] = v; return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this code gives me an object with 0: "3" in it as only result

Comment: You are not answering the question, you just sorted by key but not removed the first key..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the order and know both key and a value, you can run this code to get an array of objects where key and value are specified and order is the same.

```js
const initial = [
        {62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
        {61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
        {55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}];

    const finalOptions = [];
    for (let i=0; i<initial.length; i++) {
        let option = initial[i];
        let key = Object.keys(option)[0]; // get first and only key from option
        finalOptions.push({key:key, value: option[key]});
    }
    
    console.log(finalOptions);
```

Comment: I need an object as result not an array

Comment: Iteration order is not specified for objects in javascript. You are not able to create such. What is the reason to use object?

Comment: You are not answering the question, you just sorted by key but not removed the first key. the initial array is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to iterate over objects if they are arrays so first you can do

```
   const myObject =  {
     0:{62: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
     1:{61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00"},
     2:{55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"}
   };

   const objToArray = Object.values(myObject);  //makes the array
   const objYouWant = {}; //Initializes place to build your object

  //iterates over array you just made translating each index into a key-value pair
   const backToObject = objToArray.map((item => {
    return objYouWant[item.key] = item.value
   })
```

If you `console.log` `objYouWant` you should get

```
   {
     62: ""01:30:00 - 01:45:00",
     61: "01:30:00 - 01:45:00",
     55: "03:15:00 - 04:15:00"
   }
```

Which is I think, what you want

Comment: it just does not work.